# Wordpress Access Function From Direct Access

Tags: php, wordpress

i am writing WordPress plugin with that plugin SMS controller file is placed for twilio unfortunately i can't use WordPress functions with direct access and Twilio can't use that file it is in WordPress plugin (as it is required logged in before use plugin or touch anything inside), whatever Twilio will send it will be added as subscriber in WordPress but i can't use WordPress functions because it is direct access so it is like simple PHP. How can i perform this?

From WordPress It is like

`/wp-admin/admin.php?page=mypage` **( now i can use functions )**

By Direct Access Like Twilio Requirement

`/wp-content/plugins/pluginname/pluginfile.php` **( Now i can't, But i need to perform functions )**

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your plugin. I would start with hooking a function to the "init" proces of WordPress and listen to a unique $_GET parameter. When it's present, execute the code you want to execute.

Most WordPress plugins themselves disable direct access due to security reasons. So you won't get it working without programming something yourselves.

Comment: i can't program that much becuase WordPress Uses His Own Library to hash the password how can i perform that? and i can't set user role to subscriber with external script..

Comment: You can do both with WordPress... http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_hash_password and http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_update_user (set the role argument).

Comment: Bro... i can't use any function from direct file access.. :(

Comment: i need to access that file directly wich is placed in plugins/plugin/sms.php 
where plugins/plugin/plugin.php is accessed for wordpress dashbourd but this sms.php is for direct access and i can't use any kind of function with direct access..

Comment: Yes you can... But make sure you load WordPress core by including wp-load.php `define('SHORTINIT', true); require_once('./wp-load.php');`